# Substituir tag xml pelo nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, html-tags

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda para sanar um problema que estou encarando. Eu preciso renomear as tags de um arquivo xml pelo nodejs. Pensei em fazer o uso de regex, usar o fs para ler o arquivo, mas fiquei meio perdido.

```
<RESULTS>
<ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="DATA_CRIACAO"><![CDATA[24/08/18]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="PLACA"><![CDATA[ABC456]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="CHASSI"><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></COLUMN>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="DATA_CRIACAO"><![CDATA[23/08/18]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="PLACA"><![CDATA[ABC123]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="CHASSI"><![CDATA[YYYYYYYYYYYYYY]]></COLUMN>
</ROW>
```

Dentro de ROW temos ....., eu preciso renomear cada linha dessa para o conteúdo que está dentro de NAME.

Por exemplo, renomear de:

```
<COLUMN NAME="DATA_CRIACAO"><![CDATA[24/08/18]]></COLUMN>
```

para:

```
<DATA_CRIACAO><![CDATA[24/08/18]]></DATA_CRIACAO>
```

Agradeço a atenção, obrigado!

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte expressão regular dentro de um `replace` para ter o resultado que você deseja:

```
/<COLUMN NAME="(.+)">(.+)<\/COLUMN>/gm
```

O código completo será o seguinte:

```js
const REGEX = /<COLUMN NAME="(.+)">(.+)<\/COLUMN>/gm;
let xml = `<ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="DATA_CRIACAO"><![CDATA[24/08/18]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="PLACA"><![CDATA[ABC456]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="CHASSI"><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></COLUMN>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="DATA_CRIACAO"><![CDATA[23/08/18]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="PLACA"><![CDATA[ABC123]]></COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="CHASSI"><![CDATA[YYYYYYYYYYYYYY]]></COLUMN>
</ROW>`;

xml = xml.replace(REGEX, '<$1>$2</$1>');

console.log(xml);
```

A expressão acima realiza os seguinte passos:

- `<COLUMN NAME="` combina o conjunto literal `<COLUMN NAME="` (case sensitive);
- Captura o grupo `(.+)`:

  - `.+` combina qualquer caractere (exceto terminações de linhas);
  - O quantificador `+` Combina entre uma e `n` vezes, quantas vezes forem possíveis;
- `">` combina os caracteres literais `">` (case sensitive);
- Captura o grupo `(.+)`:

  - `.+` combina qualquer caractere (exceto terminações de linhas);
  - O quantificador `+` Combina entre uma e `n` vezes, quantas vezes forem possíveis;
- `<` combina o caractere literal `<` (case sensitive);
- `\/` combina o caractere literal `/` (case sensitive);
- `COLUMN>` combina os caracteres literais `COLUMN>` (case sensitive).